# What does mvn do when using rf (resume from) in a parallel build?

Tags: maven, parallel-processing

If I ask mvn to do a parallel build (-T1C) and it fails on one module, what will it do when I ask it to resume from (-rf) the broken module?

I've looked on maven's documentation but found nothing, nor on stackoverflow.

Comment: First which Maven version do you use? BTW: Have you tried it?

Comment: 3.6.3.  I could indeed try it, true.  In the absence of any knowledge/doc, I will investigate.

Comment: From experiments on a very parallel project it seems to be able to work out which modules had already been built successfully to quite a large degree, but not completely, which I guess is reasonable given it probably does not store what passed and what did not anywhere, I presume.  Unless there's a definitive answer, I'll put this in an answer.

Comment: Though further experiments suggest it did not build everything it should have, so I am not sure it's reliable in general.

Comment: Parallel build works. I have worked with builds container 800+ modules without problems. First test I would suggest is to delete your local cache and simply build your project via `mvn clean package` and see if everything works without any issue...furthermore I really strongly recommend to upgrade your maven version and also check all plugins your are using and upgrade to the most recent as well... (older plugins have issues; also older Maven versions...(Maven 3.8.2 has fixed several issues related to parallel build)...

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12316922&version=12349965

Comment: The next question is: What exactly failed? compilation error ? Please post the message ?

Comment: To be clear, a full parallel build from scratch works fine.  The situation I am describing is resuming a failed parallel build using -rf after fixing the problem.  In one case the -rf seemed to miss compiling one of the modules.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for full information. Maybe it's a problem in Maven core or not... and maybe a case which is not yet working? Or an other edge case? Or something in general?

Comment: Well as I say, it simply did not compile one of the modules (in particular, there was an error in the module which was only picked up when I did a fresh full parallel build).  I don't have time to do extensive experiments to narrow down the exact conditions under which it will fail unfortunately.

Comment: Ok...then it's impossible to help.

Comment: As an aside, mvnd seems to be more reliable at this.
https://github.com/mvndaemon/mvnd

Comment: How could you know? If you don't know the root cause...